# Tags for "fedora": Need "fedora20" tag (maybe)

Tags: support, tags

Fedora 20 has hit USB sticks (so to say) and it could be the time to add the "fedora20" (sic) tag.

Reminder: the following tags currently exist.

It's kinda uneven, but indicating the Fedora version is indeed of some interest as the distribution's behaviour may change heavily:

```
fedora [generic, clearly]
fedoracore [the old fedora name]
fedora8
fedora9
fedora12
fedora13 [fedora-13 aliased to it]
fedora14
fedora15
fedora17
fedora-ds [not for a Fedora Release but for the Fedora Directory Server. Hah!]
```

For those interested in history:

[Fedora Historical Schedules](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/HistoricalSchedules)

[Fedora Release Names](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/History_of_Fedora_release_names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't as such a create tag function that allows them to be created ahead of time. Anyone with [create tag privilege](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/create-tags) who asks a question or edits the tags may create a new tag. Generally we wait for that to happen.

Aside:
There are less than 800 questions with [fedora](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora) or some release specific version. This is probably due to Fedora not being popular as a production environment.

Comment: True; I was just looking for the "fedora20" tag and, well, it wasn't there yet. And I don't have enough privileges to do it. Let's wait.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Ah, you should have linked to your question and requested that tag be added, I (or someone else) would have done this for you. I have added the tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks Iain, perfect.

Comment: Indeed, Fedora is not often used for production environments. We even have [a question about just that](http://serverfault.com/q/40408/126632). I'd be more inclined to synonymize all of these tags...